# Try Catch Statement Infinite Loop

Tags: java, validation, user-input

I was working on come code for a physics lab to crunch standard deviation for my data (not part of the lab, I don't post my homework on stack overflow) just to make my life a bit easier. I wanted to handle errors that could occur if incorrect data was entered, but whenever I input incorrect data I just get an infinite loop with my error message printing out each iteration. Here is the prolematic code:

```
// Continue to ask the user for an integer until a correct input is
    // given
    boolean integerCheck = false;
    while (integerCheck == false) {
        try {
            numberOfPoints = input.nextInt();
            integerCheck = true;
        } catch(InputMismatchException mismatch) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer.");
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if anybody has seen this before, and how they fixed it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Where do you set `integerCheck` back to `false`?

Comment: Do you need to? Because if I am getting an infinite loop, then it is already set to false. I want it to keep asking the user for input until correct input is given.

Comment: NickP your answer has already been given by @Tom

Comment: @Tom you are completely correct. Should have checked around more! That solved my problem!